# Splitting name using hyphen and iteration

Tags: python-3.x

I wish to make a function which would split a name using hyphens("-")

```
 def tag(name):
    for word in list(name):
        *something*
    return variable
print(tag('Richard'))
```

> desired output

```
'R-i-c-h-a-r-d-'
```

Comment: ... that would be `'-'.join("Richard")` ... where exactly is your problem?

Comment: check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/

you want to use the `join` operator on string, which operates on the 'joiner' (in your case, '-') and accepts either a list, or another string.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the join function on a string, which operates on the 'joiner' (in your case, '-') and accepts either a list, or another string.

So, you could have `'-'.join('Richard')`,

or

```
def tag(name):
  return '-'.join(name)
```

Comment: What if I want to use iteration

Comment: @Code2501 then it would seem like you're trying to solve a homework problem, and we can't help with that

Answer (score -1):

Try this below :

```
def tag(name):
    output = name[0]
    for i in name[1:]:
        output += '-' + i
    return output

print(tag('Richard'))
```

OR

```
def tag(name):
    return '-'.join("Richard")
```

Comment: string.join would be more pythonic and cleaner.

Comment: VERY inefficient - you construct plenty of immuteable string intermediates that need to be created and destroyed. This kind of thing is exactly what the `join()` function on iterables is for.

Comment: What if I want to use iteration?

Comment: @Code2501 this one _does_ use iteration, just not in the exact format you are wanting.